# How do I update my VS 2017 to the latest version of SSDT?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using VS 2017. I'm starting a project which involves SQL Server Analysis Services and I wanted to make sure I had the latest SSDT installed in VS. I first upgraded VS to 15.9.5. I looked and noticed that SSDT was still at 15.1.61901, instead of 15.8.2 (the latest version). I then downloaded and installed the latest SSDT and the version is still at 15.1.61901 (see below). Am I missing a step here?

[image]

Comment: Either open Visual Studio Installer and update. Check [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017). SSRS and SSAS are available as separate VS extensions too

Comment: The VS Installer does not show SSDT as needing to be installed or updated. And, as I said in my post, I've already downloaded, and installed, the separate SSDT extension.

Comment: What did you install? Did you select to update an existing installation or did you chose to install it separately? There's no other way to install or update SSDT. Its components are Visual Studio extensions. The standalone installer contains the extensions and the VS Shell.

Comment: The version number you see in `About` can be deceptive. I've installed the latest SSDT as a separate instance because I need SSIS and it breaks on every update. I get the same version number you do in `About`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thank you. That is good to know. I guess I'll assume I have the latest version.

Comment: It's rather annoying actually. Check the SSIS version number - it's empty. I check the SSDT download site daily to see if there's a new version and which of the many bugs I encounter have been fixed. And every time I update VS itself I need to check whether something broke in SSIS

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm not a huge fan of SSDT. I've spent a lot of time in it working on SSIS projects and now I need to spend more time in it working on an Analysis Services project. I wish there was a good alternative. SSDT just feels like it was put together by Microsoft summer interns.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Add/Remove Programms" and check the Version-Number:

[image: Add/Remove programs]

You'll see the "build number" here. To translate it to the "release number" go to SSDT download page and check the version informations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Version Information:
Release number: 15.9.0
Build Number: 14.0.16186.0
Release date: January 28, 2019